# Is there a more general definition of convolution or is this abuse of notation?

Tags: probability, definition, convolution

In the below link under (LTI Systems with Random Inputs:) the author writes: [image]

https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter10/10_2_2_LTI_systems_with_random_inputs.php

How do you convolve two functions with different arguments?  What specifically does $h(\tau) * R_X(-\tau)$ mean?

I know that $(h * R_X)(\tau) = h(\tau) * R_X(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(\alpha)R_X(\tau - \alpha) d\alpha$, but how does $h(\tau) * R_X(-\tau)$ become the integral in the picture?

Comment: Because it is $h(\tau)\ast R_X(- \tau)$

Comment: Define a new function $S(t) = R(-t) $ and convolve $h$ and $S$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams But then you get $h * \tau = \int h(\alpha) S(\tau - \alpha)d\alpha = \int h(\alpha) R_X(-(\tau - \alpha))d\alpha = \int h(\alpha)R_X(-\tau + \alpha)$ which isn't equal to $\int h(\alpha) R_X(\tau - \alpha)$?

Comment: I meant to write $\int h(\alpha)R_X(\tau + \alpha)$ in the last equation of my previous comment.

Comment: One may write $$ (f*g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g(x-y) \,dy, $$ but writing $f(x)*g(x)$ or $f(y)*g(y)$ instead of $(f*g)(x)$ is an abuse of notation, and it is often done.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If it's an abuse of notation than how does that notation yield the integral in the picture?

Comment: It looks like an abuse of notation:
$h(-\tau) * R_X(\tau) := (\hat h * R_X)(\tau)$
where $\hat h(\tau) = h(-\tau).$

Comment: @md2perpe But how does the notation given give the integral in the picture?  I don't see how substituting $h^{\text{^}}(\tau)$ shows the equality.

Comment: $$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} h(\alpha) R_X(\tau+\alpha) \, d\alpha
= \{ \alpha \to -\alpha \} \\
= \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} h(-\alpha) R_X(\tau-\alpha) \, (-d\alpha) \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} h(-\alpha) R_X(\tau-\alpha) \, d\alpha \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat h(\alpha) R_X(\tau-\alpha) \, d\alpha \\
= (\hat h * R_X)(\tau)
$$